# Situar teclado virtual en pantalla de jquery

Tags: jquery

Necesito poder situal este teclado virtual de jquery  en una zona de la pantalla, ahora mismo me sale situado en la parte superior izquierda.

De esta pagina saqué el teclado:
https://mottie.github.io/Keyboard/index.html

```js
$('#idUsuario').keyboard({ layout: 'qwerty' })
```

```css
.Absolute-Center {
  
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%; left: 40%; bottom: 0; right: 0;
 }

#contenedor{
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/vader/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/virtual-keyboard/1.28.7/css/keyboard.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/virtual-keyboard/1.28.7/js/jquery.keyboard.min.js"></script>

<div class="Absolute-Center is-Responsive  ">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
   <div id="contenedor"> 
    <div class="form-group input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="idUsuario"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"  title="N&uacute;meros y letra may&uacute;scula y sin espacios"  name="txtUsuario" placeholder="Introduzca DNI o CIF" required />          
     </div>
     <div id="idTextoError" class="alert alert-danger" style="display:none"></div>
     
   </div>  
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Te da error porque está cargando primero el script del teclado y luego jquery. También te falta el CSS de jquery-ui. Lo cambio. ¿Dónde quieres colocarlo?

Comment: Muchas gracias,  en mi ejemplo, tengo el input centrado en la pagina pero el teclado sale arriba a la izquierda. Me gustaría que el teclado aparezca donde este situado el campo.

Comment: ¿Tienes más CSS en tu página? Como ves en el ejemplo, funciona sin problemas así que tiene que haber otro CSS que esté interfiriendo y enviándote el teclado a la esquina superior izquierda

Comment: Con el CSS que has puesto sigue saliendo bien.

Comment: Fijate ahora en el ejemplo, como el teclado siempre sale en la parte superior izquierda.

Comment: Creo que el problema es que te falta poner la referencia a jquery-ui.js. Acabo de editar tu pregunta y creo que así funciona. Prueba a añadirla en tu proyecto y me dices.

Comment: Exacto, Muchas gracias. Añade una respuesta que la pueda valorar si te parece.

Comment: Ya está publicada la respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el problema es que te falta poner la referencia a jquery-ui.js.

```js
$('#idUsuario').keyboard({ layout: 'qwerty'});
```

```css
.Absolute-Center {
  
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
 }

#contenedor{
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
 }
 
 .ui-keyboard {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/vader/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/virtual-keyboard/1.28.7/css/keyboard.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/virtual-keyboard/1.28.7/js/jquery.keyboard.min.js"></script>

<div class="Absolute-Center is-Responsive  ">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
   <div id="contenedor"> 
    <a href="http://www.grupolacana.com">
     <div id="logo"></div>
    </a>
    <div id="logo-error" style="display:none"></div>
    <form  method="post" action="javascript:login();" name="loginForm"  id="loginForm">
     <center><H5 CLASS="acceso "><div class="col-md-12" id="lblRegistro">- SOLICITAR CODIGO DE ACCESO -</div></h5></center>
     <div class="form-group input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="idUsuario"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"  title="N&uacute;meros y letra may&uacute;scula y sin espacios"  name="txtUsuario" placeholder="Introduzca DNI o CIF" required />          
     </div>
     <div id="idTextoError" class="alert alert-danger" style="display:none"></div>
     <div class="form-group input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
      <input  type="password"  class="form-control"  title="Introduzca  clave." name='txtClave' id="idClave" placeholder="Clave" required />     
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn-sm   btn btn-primary btn-block"><strong>Aceptar</strong></button>
     </div>
    </form>  
   </div>  
  </div>
 </div>
```